Unexpected behaviour: Single pole RC LPF on output of op-amp buffer
I'm working on a project to show students how to use a Raspberry Pi to take automated I-V measurements of diodes.
We've already done this using an Arduino, but there is a strong desire to use the Pi instead.  The Arduino method was simply to generate a PWM signal, and low-pass it to create a variable DC voltage (and then take voltage measurements across the diode):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Crude, but works.  VM1 and VM2 give the volt-drop, and VM2/R1 gives the current.  The impedance of the Arduino pin is approximately 40 Ω, so the 680 μF cap gives a cut-off frequency of around 5 Hz.
Using the Pi:
Using the Pi, the first issue is that the logic levels are 3.3 V.  We need a higher DC voltage for a meaningful I-V curve (5 V is an ideal minimum for a p-n diode).  I used a sparkfun logic level shifter that I had lying around (based on a BSS138), to get a 0–5 V PWM signal.  I then added a capacitor on the output:

simulate this circuit
Note: The level shifter would probably be hidden from our students, so they don't need to understand its role.  At most, it would be treated as a 'black box'.
Problem 1:  I tried R-C networks with approximately 5 Hz cut-off, with R values from 0–1 MΩ, but the voltage across C1 never exceeds +3 V, even though the PWM is 0–5 V.
I quickly assumed (MOAFU) this was some kind of loading issue, so added a simple op-amp buffer.  This would also be hidden from our students, as they haven't done op-amps at this point:

simulate this circuit
The impedance of the LM741 should be around 70 ohms, which ought to give a cut-off of 3.3Hz.  However:
Problem 2: There is no output voltage until duty ratio > 70%.
To me, this looks like capacitor thresholding behaviour, possibly due to low charge current.  Adding a 100 Ω resistor in series with C1 results in a decent response (although fairly non-linear).  My feeling is that adding the 100 Ohm resistor re-enforces my theory about the charge current being too low.
However, I would like to actually understand what causes the 2 problems above, and would appreciate any input from the community.
Edit: I forgot to state that the op-amp is currently powered from a +/- 9V external supply.
The reason for using the 741 is partly because we use them with our students, due to the easily-exploitable issues they have.  However, yes, I should use something better in this case.  I want to understand the nature of the issue, though - which might help me choose a more appropriate op-amp.

Please don't abuse ICs by putting 680uF capacitors directly on IC pins. That's definitely not the way of putting an RC filter to an MCU output. You are missing the "R".

The impedance of the Arduino pin is approximately 40 Ohms, so the 680uF cap gives a cut-off frequency of around 5Hz. this would also kill the pin as the peak current (whilst the cap is empty) could be more than 100 mA which is way beyond the Arduino's limits. so added a simple op-amp buffer what supply voltage did you use for op amp? If it's 5V then make sure the op amp is happy to be supplied from 5V. Also the op amp is probably not capable of driving 680uF. Finally, make sure the output swings the rails close enough. LM741 is a poor choice tbh.

The opamp both needs to be happy to be supplied at 5V, and it needs to be able to accept 5V on its input and be able to generate 5V on its output when supplied with 5V. I doubt the LM741 will be OK with any of that.

Can you provide exact details for how you're powering the 741?  As @ChintalagiriShashank says, at first glance, the 741 seems unsuited to your task, but we can't really pin the issue on this until we know the power scheme for the chip.  There are also some other issues, pointed out in the answers.

Also, the Pi lacks A/D, so what will you do with the analog signals you generate to automate your process?

Please, please don't use a 741. That chip should have been obsoleted decades ago.

@Justme I do understand that is a general rule, but why?  And why does it work on the Arduino outputs?

@RohatKılıç How can one tell what capacitance the op-amp can drive?  Even though the 741 is not ideal, would a different op-amp improve this particular issue?

@Hearth is the issue specifically because of using a 741?  If so, what is the actual cause of the issue?

@JoeMills the amount of the capacitive load a particular op amp can drive is normally stated in the datasheet – Could be either as a parameter such as $C_L$ or explained within stability performance graphs. For example, if you check TS321 you'll see different behavioural graphs for different capacitive loads. But still, 680 uF is really too much. You may want to add a series resistance just like in the precision rectifiers.

@JoeMills No, you'll have this issue with any op amp, but please don't use a 741 regardless. They're so bad.

Problem 1 is caused by the transistor being off when both left and right side are at 3.3V. Only the 10k resistor will pull up to 5V. In essence, the MCU will push and pull up to 0V and 3.3V throuh 1kohm, but the pull to 5V is done much slower via 11 kohms.
Problem 2 is caused by many issues. You cannot put a capacitor to op-amp output and expect it to work. Also you don't show the supply voltages, but assuming you use 0V and 5V as supplies, and neither the input or output are not rated to supply voltages. It does not have rail-to-rail inputs or outputs.

I appreciate your input on my issues.  Could you please help clarify some points raised in your answer for me:


Specifically why does the slower pull to 5V affect the voltage across the capacitor, but not the un-filtered PWM (which is 0 - 5V).


I completely recognise that putting a cap onto an op-amp output is not recommended, but I want to understand why.  I also want to understand why this technique works on the output of the Arduino?


I forgot to include the supply voltages.  +/-9V to the op-amp, from an external supply.  Without the filter, the output of the 741 is 0-5V PWM.

@JoeMills 2) an opamp will oscillate with such a huge capacitor, and if it can somehow handle it (most likely this 741 cannot) then you need to watch out for driving capability at your frequency of interest. A unity-gain buffer gas shunt feedback at the output, which means an inductive kind of Zout, which will resonate with a capacitor at frequencies below UGF. Your Arduino output doesn't use feedback, but it probably suffers to drive such a big capacitor. I'd personally always place an explicit resistor to have more certainty on the LPF.

@Designalog That's very useful.  Not allowed to thank you here, but I am thinking it.

@JoeMills Because without capacitor the 10k can pull the output to 5V directly without charging any capacitor. With capacitor the MCU output will push-pull with high current between 0 and 3.3V but from 3V3 to 5V the 10k resistor charges slowly with small current. And op-amps cannot drive capacitive loads as they require a lot of current fast and they can't do that so that's why there should be no capacitance on op-amp output directly. Or even directly on MCU output. That's why you have the 'R' in an RC filter so you don't short circuit your outputs and overload them.
